# Using ARKit and LiDAR to scan an object and get dimensions of said object

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, scanning, lidar

Im developing a prototype which should be able to scan a real-world object and create a 3D representation of it. It then needs to get spatial data about said object (like the width, height and depth of the object).

Currently I've been able to create a 3D scan of the object using the following guide: https://medium.com/zeitraumgruppe/what-arkit-3-5-and-the-new-ipad-pro-bring-to-the-table-d4bf25e5dd87

I've then been able to view that 3D model using SceneKit, and export it to a computer, however I stille need to figure out how to get the spacial dimensions of the object on the phone.

I'm thinking I also need to "crop" away some of the unwanted data captured by the LiDAR sensor (like the floor of the object). Another solution could be to only "scan" what is inside a predefined bounding box, as Apple is doing with the "Scanning and detecting 3D Objects", as shown here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects

I am, however, at a loss, as too where I should look for more precise info.

Any tips?

Comment: any success in your prototype?

Comment: Yes. Firstly I used ARKit to show a virtual box, then used Euclid library to crop the 3D model to the specified virtual box. https://github.com/nicklockwood/Euclid.